# CORS in App Engine application (python)

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to do x-domain request between 2 applications in app engine. In one hand, i have my API and in the other hand i have my "client application". I have been reading so much about CORS; i think i know how it works, and here comes the problem: It doesn't work. Simple request works, but the problem comes when i try to do non-simple request (with credentials). I have this code to handle the headers and allow CORS:

```
try:
    _origin = self.request.headers['Origin']
except:
    _origin = "http://myapp"
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", _origin)
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept")
self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
self.response.out.write( json.dumps( _response ) )
```

EDITED: I'm working with both applications under the same domain (http://app1.domain.com and http://app2.domain.com).

As i cannot use wildcards for request with credentials transference, i detect the Origin and i set the Allow-Origin in each request for this domain. In my client app i have this code to make the http requests:

```
jQuery.extend( {
postJSON: function ( _url, _data, _callback) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
        },
        headers : {
            "x-requested-with" : "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        success: _callback,
        error: function() {
            _msg = "<strong>Error: </strong> Error en la petición HTTP (nivel de protocolo).";
            _error( _msg );
        }
    });
}
```

});

In order to handle the request, i have these methods:

```
@decorators.notAllowed
def get(self):
    pass

@decorators.isNotLogged
@decorators.language
def post(self):
    common._responseJSON( self, CU._doLogin( self ) )

def options(self):
    common._responseJSON( self, CU._doLogin( self ) )
```

This is the OPTIONS request and response:

```
Request URL:http://myapi/method
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:myapi
Origin:http://myapp
Referer:http://myapp/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11

Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://myapp
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:114
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 16 Nov 2012 11:31:40 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

And this is the HTTP POST request:

```
    Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://myapp
Referer:http://myapp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
```

But when the browser tries to do the POST request, it fails:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi/method/. Origin http://myapp is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Any idea? I'm getting insane with this problem... What i have to do in the OPTIONS http request? Maybe i'm not handling it in right way... :-/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have get, post, and options methods defined on your request handler? Can you add your request handler code to your question?

Comment: Yes @AaronHampton, here you have the code for the handlers ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to provide the response from the POST request? Are you sure that the Access-Control-Allow-* headers are set on both the OPTIONS and the POST request?

Comment: When are you setting the headers? In "common._responseJSON"? If so, can you provide the code for "common._responseJSON"?

Comment: @monsur The Access-Control-Allow is setuped for OPTIONS and POST requests, so i think that's not the problem.

Comment: @AaronHampton the code of common._responseJSON is the first code that i show. I setup the headers there.

Comment: I'm running both applications under the same domain, so it is a cross-subdomain request...

Comment: A couple things:
  (1) sub or not, it doesn't matter. They're different domains. That's it.
  (2) you can remove "origin, content-type, accept" - they're simple headers and always allowed/present, specially "origin" for CORS.
  (3) Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to 'h ttp://myapp.appspot.com' for now, w/o a condition to simplify and see if that works.
  (4) there's also 'Access-Control-Max-Age' to cache preflight requests.
Also, are you sure the protocols match? e.g. you always use either http or https.

Comment: @alex Thanks! I tried to change the domain (replacing the var _origin for only one origin, my app), and it does not work. My doubt is: Have i to put http://myapp.appspot.com or http://myapp.mydomain.com ? I'm using a domain with this app... Also i have set the header "Access-Control-Max-Age" to 1 day, and now it fails in the preflight request. Finally, i have checked it and i am sure that the protocols match (i'm using only http).

Comment: I think my problem is that i'm not handling the OPTIONS request in the right way... What i have to do in this request? Only to set the headers? And what i need to send to the browser?

Comment: Uhm... yes, only headers. Interesting that it fails. As for the domain, it should be exactly the same as the one you're accessing it from with the browser. For instance, if you're pointing your browser to an h ttp://myapp.appspot.com/testcors.html (where your JS code gets executed), then on myapi.appspot.com (where your JS code connects to)  you should respond with that same origin: h ttp://myapp.appspot.com in this case. There's also a nice tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: @alex That's exactly what my code does :-/. It is too strange because sometimes it works, other times it does not work... I can understand why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!! It was so simple; i feel a little bit stupid... If you look at the code, you will see some decorators before some method handlers. That's the problem: Sometimes i send content to the browser trough the decorators. And this content has no Allow-Control-* headers. And this is the reason why sometimes it failed and sometimes not (it fails when the decorator replies)

I have configured the headers in all the decorators which send content and it works fine :-). Thanks to all for your help, really!!

Comment: I had to read a couple times before I realized I was making the same mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error with Google APIs. Since only 3 or 4 days, all CORS requests to Google APIs fail if they contain the **x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest** header, causing that "*Origin [...] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*" error. It was working until those last days.

You may have the same problem with App Engine CORS requests. Try removing the following lines :

```
headers : {
        "x-requested-with" : "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!! That's not the problem, because i have analyse the preflight request and the server says "Ok, you can do the request". I mean, i send and i hope to receive this field. Anyway, i have tried and it still doesn't work... I'm getting crazy!